# "Пространный" как синоним "абстрактного, размытого"

Tags: синонимы

Вот собственно хотелось бы поинтересоваться: являются ли они синонимами? Всегда использовал данное слово как определение чего-то неконкретного, неясного, поддающегося разной трактовке/формулировке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В моём понимании это "излишне длинное толкование чего-либо", из которого трудно быстро выявить нужную суть. Легкий оттенок отрицательного отношения к материалу (устному или письменному) со стороны человека, рассчитывавшего на простой и ясный ответ. Не всегда сам материал в этом виноват, здесь есть элемент субъективной оценки. Я не назвал бы прямыми синонимами этого слова "абстрактный" (отвлечённый, формализованный, в общих понятиях) и "размытый" (неясно изложенный и не по существу темы материал), поскольку основной момент здесь "длинный".